# How to pass an argument into a Highcharts-Function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to draw some lines (paths) into a Highcharts-Chart. When exporting the chart, the lines should be a little different. Therefore I created a Highcharts-Function, which I call on »load« and »redraw«. I just need to pass one little argument when calling the function, but this doesn´t work. How can I pass the argument?

Here´s the relevant code detail:

```
Highcharts.linien = function (r) { //generating the lines with my r-argument }

...

chart: {
   events: {
   load: Highcharts.linien(0)
}

exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        chart: {
        events: {
            load: Highcharts.linien(15)
        }
    }
}
```

And here´s a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3ywb3gq/2/) without using the argument.

Besides: If anyone has a clue, how to destroy my svg-group (linienGruppe) on »redraw«, I would also be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function(){
      Highcharts.linien.call(this, 0);
    }
  }
}

exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function(){
          Highcharts.linien.call(this, 15);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, using `call()` you can pass on `this` object to your function.

And regarding destroying group, first store somewhere your group, so later you can destroy that object, like this:

```
if(this.linienGruppe) {
    this.linienGruppe.destroy();
}

this.linienGruppe = linienGruppe;
```

And working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t3ywb3gq/4/

Answer (score 1):

`Highcharts.linien(0)` & `Highcharts.linien(15)` are both function executions/invocations and not handlers. A handler is a function itself. Since you want to pass a parameter, I suggest you create an inline anonymous function with one line that calls your created method with appropriate arguments like below;

```
chart: {
   events: {
   load: function(){
       Highcharts.linien(0);
   }
}

exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(){
               Highcharts.linien(15);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3ywb3gq/3/)

Comment: I tried this already, but as you can see in your fiddle this doesn´t work either. The lines are not been rendered. Console shows: »Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'g' of undefined«, which is the same as calling Highcharts.linien(0) directly.